# How to rename a file in the innermost subdirectory of a directory tree (4 levels in) to match the toplevel directory name in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a file named default.xex that is located in XBLA_Unpacked/DirectoryName/Subdirectory/000D0000/default.xex.
I am trying to rename default.xex to be DirectoryName.xex. I managed to accomplish this with File.Move() but it pulled the .xex file up into XBLA_Unpacked, so both DirectoryName and DirectoryName.xex are located there. I need to be able to rename the .xex file while also keeping it inside the 000D000 subdirectory.

This is my current code which renames the .xex file and moves it up to the XBLA_Unpacked directory, as well as the code I wrote to try to move it back after it was renamed that doesn't work.

```
 static void ReNamePirs()
            {
                string homePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
                string unpackedPath = homePath + "\\XBLA_Unpacked\\";
                string reNamePath = homePath + "\\XBLA_Unpacked";
                var files = GetAllFiles(unpackedPath);
                var folders = GetAllFolders(unpackedPath);
                List<string> sourceName = Directory.GetFiles(unpackedPath, "default.xex", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
                List<string> destinationName = Directory.GetDirectories(unpackedPath, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();
                List<string> finalDestination = Directory.GetDirectories(unpackedPath, "000D0000", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

                for (int i = 0; i < sourceName.Count; i++)
                {
                    destinationName[i] = destinationName[i] + ".xex";

                    File.Move(sourceName[i], destinationName[i]);
                    
                }
                sourceName = Directory.GetFiles(reNamePath, ".xex", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

                for (int i = 0; i < sourceName.Count; i++)
                {
                    destinationName = Directory.GetDirectories(unpackedPath, "000D0000", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
                    File.Move(sourceName[i], destinationName[i]);

                }

                return;
            }
```

Comment: When you have the file path, get the desired name by applying `Path.GetDirectoryName` 3 times. Then rename it as `File.Move(originalPath, Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(originalPath), newName))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(renamePath);
FileInfo fileInfo = directoryInfo.GetFiles("default.xex", SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault();

if (fileInfo != null)
{
    string newFileName = fileInfo.FullName.Replace( Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileInfo.Name), fileInfo.Directory.Parent.Parent.Name);
    fileInfo.MoveTo(newFileName);
}
```

Comment: So this almost works. it renames the .xex file to XBLA_Unpacked instead of DirectoryName. I'm playing around with it to see if I can get it to do DirectoryName instead now.

Comment: I've updated the answer to rename to DirectoryName instead of XBLA_Unpacked

Comment: You, my friend, are my hero. I'll have to study up on how this works so I can actually understand what it is doing, but this at least solves the problem at hand. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

just Edit this part of the code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceName.Count; i++)
        {
            destinationName[i] = destinationName[i] + ".xex";
            File.Move(sourceName[i], destinationName[i]);                    
        }

        sourceName = Directory.GetFiles(reNamePath, ".xex", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < sourceName.Count; i++)
        {
            destinationName = Directory.GetDirectories(unpackedPath, "000D0000", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
            File.Move(sourceName[i], destinationName[i]);

        }
```

In the first loop, you can change the name and move it to the XBLA_Unpacked, and there is no need for the second loop. Anyway:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceName.Count; i++)
        {
            String _dest=  sourceName[i].Replace("default",sourceName[i].Split("\\")[sourceName[i].Split("\\").Length-3])
            File.Move(sourceName[i], _dest);                    
        }

        // move to XBLA_Unpacked
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(unpackedPath); 
        var Files = d.GetFiles("*.xex",SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < Files.Count; i++)
        {
            File.Move(Files[i].FullName, unpackedPath + Files[0].Name);
        }
```